# Jagged/Weird Shadows on mesh

Tags: shadows

[image]

Hi all,

I imported a .stl file into blender and at first the mesh was perfect, shadows were as expected but on the second time of importing the .stl file the shadows are as seen below. How can I fix this?

Comment: share your blend file please: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Answer (score 1):

I found that because I had the Clip Start set to 0.001 it was producing this unusual effect. However, when I bumped this up to 0.1 the shading went back to normal.